# PrimeFaces 5.1 barchart extender in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces, jqplot

I have tried with this HTML and JavaScript for a bar chat. I am using  PrimeFaces 5.1 lib. But the bar graph is not showing.

```
    <h:panelGrid styleClass="headerPanelGrid">
        <h:outputText value="No Chart To Display For Selected Options" rendered="#{null == jobStatusChart.categoryModel}" style="font-size:20px;" />
        <p:chart type="bar" id="jobStatusBarChart" model="#{jobStatusChart.categoryModel}" showDatatip="false" title="Total No. Of Jobs By Status"
            min="0" max="#{jobStatusChart.total}" style="width:600px;" animate="true" yaxisLabel="Total No. Of Jobs" 
            extender="formatBarChart" rendered="#{null != jobStatusChart.categoryModel}" barMargin="10" barPadding="5" widgetVar="statusChart"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function formatBarChart() {  this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
    renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    rendererOptions : {
        barWidth : 60
    },
    pointLabels : {
        show : true
    },
},

this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
    formatString : '%d'
},

this.cfg.legend = {
    renderer : $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
    show : true,
    placement : 'outside',
    rendererOptions : {
        seriesToggle : 'normal'
    }
};
}
```

Comment: So it works without the extender?

Comment: If the 'not showing up' is not related to the extender, please remove all that from the title, question etc...

Comment: it is working in pf 3.5 but it is not working in pf 5.1 so i need to change any jars ??

Comment: No, you need to create an [mcve] and during the creation debug…

Comment: Hello. I edited the title of your post with proper casing, this makes it easier to read.  I also changed the casing of the programming languages in the body. Hope you get your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read [Migration Guide](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide)

and see

[image: migration guide]

Then re-code the bar chart by studying [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml) and [user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf)

EDIT: you already have **extender="formatBarChart"** in your xhtml. if you set **model.setExtender("ext")** then you need to create javascript function ext() and remove function formatBarChart + extender="formatBarChart" in xhtml. Please read ***chapter 3.15 in user guide completely*** then re-ask a new proper question or edit your question properly. ***Most answers are in showcase, userguide, migration guide, change logs, github and hard-work.***

Comment: Based on what part of the question did you conclude it was migration related? And how? Code in Q seems 5.1 and up

Comment: one more doubt i am trying with extender attribute like model.setExtender("ext") in backing code,, this is working fine for pie charts but not for bar chart and line chart please help me

Comment: @SarithaReddy: then why the heck did you accept this answer?